# App crashing when trying to call Native function

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I have a native function in a Java class which returns an integer. The function definition is in my .c source file. My app is crashing while trying to call the native function. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

The java class :

```
package com.example.asish.fibseries;

/**
 * Created by Asish on 2/9/2015.
 */
public class Fib {
    public native static int NI(int n);
}
```

My source file (.c) :

```
#include "com_example_asish_fibseries_Fib.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_example_asish_fibseries_Fib_NI
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jint n){
  jint previous = -1;
  jint result = 1;
  jint i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    jint sum = previous + result;
    previous = result;
    result = sum;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Main Activity Snippet :

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
    EditText e1;
    e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView t1;
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int y;
    y = NI(n);
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(y));
}
```

Is this the logcat thing we are looking for?

--------- beginning of main
I/LoadedApk(12159): No resource references to update in package common
I/LoadedApk(12159): No resource references to update in package com.cyngn.yu
I/LoadedApk(12159): No resource references to update in package com.cyngn.yu
I/Timeline(12159): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d8f7182 time:33368817
I/Timeline(12159): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d8f7182 time:33404304
I/Timeline(12159): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:org.jtb.alogcat time:33407440
I/Timeline(12159): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2525babc time:33407834
I/Timeline(12159): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d8f7182 time:33456683

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Are you getting a Java exception, or a native crash? You should add the stacktrace from logcat to your question.

Comment: I am trying to run the app on my mobile. It says "Unfortunately the app has stopped".

Comment: Connect the device to a computer via USB so that you can take logs.

Comment: I tried that as well. Same result.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that connecting the device to a computer via USB would stop the app from crashing. I'm saying that you should collect logs of the crash over USB using `adb logcat`, and then add the relevant parts of the log to your question.

Comment: Did you loadLibrary()? What parameter do you pass to loadLibrary()? E.g. it should be "avutil" for libavutil.so. Can you find your .so library in the apk? Is it compiled for armeabi or armeabi-v7a?

Comment: I can find the .so library. It is for armeabi. Can you please elaborate on the loadLibrary() part? Thanks a lot!